# 回転行列の計算方法

Tags: 行列

[image: テトリスブロックの回転行列です]

上の図はテトリスブロックの回転行列です。
これはどのように下の結果になるのでしょうか・・・
計算の仕方が調べてもわからないです
xrー３/2と右辺のx-3/2はどのように計算されますか
初歩的な質問かもしれませんが、どうか教えてくださいm(__)m

Comment: 行列自体についてご存知で無く計算方法がわからないということでしょうか、それともこの式に限ってのことでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

sin90°は１でcos90°は０ですので、
該当の式は、

```
|xR-3/2|   |0  -1| |x-3/2|
|      | = |     | |     |
|yR-3/2|   |1   0| |y-3/2|
```

ところで２✕２行列と２✕１行列の掛け算は

```
|a  b| | A |    | aA + bB |
|    | |   | =  |         |
|c  d| | B |    | cA + dB |
```

になりますので、

```
|xR-3/2|   |-1(y-3/2)|   | -y+3/2 |
|      | = |         | = |        |
|yR-3/2|   | 1(x-3/2)|   |  x+3/2 |
         ０を掛けた項は消える
```

になります。
両辺に

```
| 3/2 |
|     |
| 3/2 |
```

を足すと

```
|xR-3/2+3/2|   | -y+3/2+3/2 |   | -y + 3 |
|          | = |            | = |        |
|yR-3/2+3/2|   | x-3/2+3/2  |   |    x   |

| xR |   | -y + 3 |
|    | = |        |
| yR |   |    x   |
```

になります。